# タグシノニムの提案 node.js ← nodejs

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

質問する際に `nodejs` とタグを入力して英語版には存在する`nodejs` -> `node.js` のタグシノニムがないことに気づきました。

`.`を抜いた表記もよくありますし、タグシノニムがあったほうが良いと思いましたので提案します。

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/synonyms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nodejs](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs)は[node.js](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)のシノニムとして設定済みです。

Comment: 了解しました、現在タグはありません。ただ経緯としては私自身が手癖で`nodejs`と打ってしまうので実際作った後にタグが存在しないことに気付いて修正してメタに提案をしたのですが、メタで提案せずに勝手に存在しないタグを使っていたほうがシノニムが作られる可能性があったということになりますよね。正規の手続きを踏むと損をする仕組みは少し嫌だなと思いました。

Comment: @jmac ironsandさんは実際「nodejs」を使ってしまったためにこの提案をされていますが、さらに何件か間違ったタグ付けが起きるのを待つべきということですか？このシノニムは本家でもよく使われるようですし、ドットなしのnodejsに別の意味を持たせることもないでしょうから、作っておいてもいいと私は思うのですが、なるべく作らないほうがいいものなのですか？（パフォーマンス上の問題があるとか）